# Animate object instances following multiple paths

Tags: animation, bezier-curves

I have a multiple curves construction (as one object) that is animated on slow appearance by time (the curves round bevel animated). Now I need to add the same object at the beginning of each path (so that each curve had its own head). Any ideas on how to make it? [image]

Comment: Do you need them as curves or would it be enough if the result is a mesh?

Comment: Mesh is alright as long as it preserves the animation

Comment: how/what did you animate? Curve parameter? locations? That's why providing a blend file and/or more informations is useful. Then questions wouldn't be necessary...

Comment: The path is appearing. The curves round bevel parameter is animated. I mentioned it. I can not share a working project but here is an example of what is meant by "stroke appearance"  https://i2.wp.com/css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/animate-stroke-full.gif